# Issue when trying to apply a @media query with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I'm trying to apply a `@media` query so when the max-width reach `991px` a `padding-left` will be added to the class, but nothing happens when the `max-width` reach `991px` and the main of the page start to wrap under the `aside`, I'm using bootstrap and here is a part of the Code  :

**CSS**

```
@media(max-width : 991px) {
    .mainIcon {
        padding-left: 47px;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="mainin">
      <div class="container-fixed mainIcon">
        <div class="row mainFoto">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="images/code_big.png" alt="">
            <a class="boutonCode">Code</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="images/tutoriel_big.png" alt="">
            <a class="boutonTutoriel">Tutoriels</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="images/foucha_big.png" alt="">
            <a class="boutonfoucha">PROJECTS</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <header class="globalTitle">
        <a href="" class="atitle"><h1 class="title">Turn Your Brean <span>On</span></h1></a>
        <h2 class="subtitle">design the future</h2>
        </header>
      </div>

    </section>
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://zerubeus.github.io/)

when i inspect the page and try to reduce the width of the browser once he is less than `991px` i see that the padding-left is not applied , i can't figure out how to fix this !

[image]

Comment: can you post more of your CSS? it's obviously getting applied but it's being overwritten which means it's most likely a hierarchy issue

Comment: this is the css https://github.com/zerubeus/myResources/blob/master/main_css.less

Comment: by the way I'm using LESS-CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you're calling your media query at the top of the page but the regular styles for `.mainIcon` below it. This is causing the media query to be overwritten by the normal styles which would explain the adjusted `padding-left` being crossed out when you expect the element. A good rule of thumb is to always include your media queries below your other CSS (or at least under the `class`/`id`/etc. you're looking to change).

try:

```
.mainIcon {
  width: 99%;
  padding-top: 14%;
  padding-left: 20%;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .mainIcon {
    padding-left: 47px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px)
{
.mainIcon {
        padding-left: 47px;
    }
}
```

or use !important

```
padding-left: 47px !important;
```